# Error on compiling project with library (Aide)

Tags: java, android, aide-ide, aide

I'm using aide to compile my projects on Android. I added the library as follows:

```java
org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9
```

But at compile time I get the following error:

[image]

I already tried using the:

```json
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

But it didn't solve anything, I saw a question here on Stack Overflow saying to use `guava-android`, even so it didn't.

Comment: Kindly add the full stack trace

Comment: @Taranmeet Singh how i can make it?

Comment: You can check for logs in logcat on Android studio then paste them in your question

Answer (score 0):

Open your app build.gradle file (located inside app folder). You'll find something like this:

```
...
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ...
    minSdkVersion ...
    targetSdkVersion ...
    versionCode ...
    versionName ...
}
...
```

So here, set the `minSdkVersion` to **26**. It will look like this after changed:

```
...
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ...
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion ...
    versionCode ...
    versionName ...
}
...
```